# How to check if a docker network with a given subnet/gateway exists?

Tags: docker

Is there a docker command that allows checking if there is a network already with a given IP? I need to create a new docker network and know its IP address.

In bash I could do something like:

```
docker network inspect $(docker network ls -q) | grep "address"
```

And check if it returns anything. But uses both the pipe `|` and the `grep` program, while I think there should be a simpler way of doing this using docker only commands.

Comment: Would `docker network inspect $(docker network ls -q) | grep "address"` fit your needs?

Comment: @AdamBarreiro : This basiacally does what I need to do, but uses both the pipe `|` and the `grep` programs, while I was wondering if docker had a means of its own to solve this. Admittedly, this is more efficient than looping, so I'll edit my question.